# «В этом тексте есть ошибки?» — «Есть — две» / «Есть, две»

Tags: пунктуация

Оба варианта корректны?

> «В этом тексте есть ошибки?» — «Есть — две».

> «В этом тексте есть ошибки?» — «Есть, две».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Лучше написать так:

***«В этом тексте есть ошибки?» — «Есть, две».***

**Пояснение**

Полный текст: *Да, **есть**, в этом тексте **две** ошибки.*

Это ***БСП***, отношения **пояснительные**, обозначаются двоеточием или (при отсутствии интонационного предупреждения) запятой. В неполном предложении лучше поставить **запятую.**

2. Можно ли пояснение обозначить **тире?**

*Да, **есть** — в этом тексте **две** ошибки.*

В общем случае тире возможно, об этом говорит и [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189#pp189): У меня правило  (: —) никакого кофепития перед сном. Пояснение в этом случае носит **присоединительный** характер.

Интонационно это понижение тона перед второй частью.  Но в сокращенном варианте такая запись **менее понятна** для прочтения, ведь тире может быть и **разделительным** (с повышением голоса): *Есть — две.*